# Changing money at Antalya airport, Turkey, late at night

Tags: airports, turkey, exchange, ayt

I am flying from Antalya Turkey to Manchester UK leaving at 02:35 hours. Can I change Turkish Liras to Pounds Sterling at the airport at that time?

This will very late Friday evening or very early Saturday morning. It will still be Turkish Bank Holiday for Bayram at this time.

Comment: Probably, but you'll get ripped off.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about changing your money in Turkey -- is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

[TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g297962-i772-k5439550-Money_exchange_in_Antalya-Antalya_Turkish_Mediterranean_Coast.html) has:

> There are 24-hour exchange bureaux (döviz bürosu) in the arrivals hall at Antalya International Airport that offer rates comparable to those offered by bureaux in the city.
>
> Count the money you’re given carefully and save your currency-exchange receipts (bordro), as you may need them to reconvert Turkish liras at the end of your stay.
>
> US dollars, GBP's and euros are easily changed at exchange bureaux. They are also often accepted as payment without being changed. Rates are similar whichever bureau you go to, Bureaux are open long hours (at a minimum, between 9am and 7pm). You will usually need to show your passport when changing cash.

It is from 23 May 2012, 06:21 but passenger numbers have grown since then (except they dipped back in 2015) so IMO no real reason to expect that facilities have been withdrawn.